# What is the meaning of higher order derivatives like d²y/dx²

Tags: calculus, derivatives, vectors

I know velocity and acceleration are higher order derivatives of the position vector. Any other examples? What is the physical significance of higher order derivatives.?

Comment: The derivative of acceleration is known as"jerk":https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerk_(physics)#Higher_derivatives

Answer (score 0):

If $Q $ is the charge in a circuit, the current intensity is $$I=\frac {dQ}{dt} $$
and $$L .\frac {d^2Q}{dt^2} $$ is a potential difference.